# Get model ManyToManyField's through class manager

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Considering  this model structure:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    track_list = models.ManyToManyField('Track', blank=True, through='TrackToPlaylist')


class Track(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class TracktoPlaylistManager(models.Manager):
    def get_ordered_tracks(self):
        return sorted(self.get_queryset(), key=lambda x: x.votes_balance, reverse=True)

class TracktoPlaylist(models.Model):
   track = models.ForeignKey(Track)
   playlist = models.ForeignKey(Playlist)

   objects = TracktoPlaylistManager()

   @property
   def votes_balance(self):
       # here's order calculated
       return
```

I would like to access through model's manager to get sorted tracks for Playlist object. but Playlist.objects.first().track_list is a ManyToManyFieldManager object. `Playlist.objects.first().track_list.through.objects` returns this manager but i would have to filter instances  by Playlist... which is double work.

Comment: Hmm, why do you have the `through` model? Doesn't sound like necessary. You might just have `track_list` field in `Playlist` as m2m field without `through`, then have the manager directly on `Playlist` instead, right?

Comment: But I need votes for Track for every Playlist separately. And there should be a way to pull up through class manager...